# looking for backup software for personal user with 10GB

Tags: backup, ftp

I'm looking for a Windows 7 solution that will allow me to backup about 10GB of data to my hosting account through FTP.
I really love the programs that comes with CrashPlan, Mozy and JungleDisk. unfortunately they only work with their online storage. So any other recommendation will be useful.

Comment: Can you access your hosting account through SFTP, as FTP is inherently insecure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/syncback-hub.html). I've used it at work for simple backups but also for complicated schemes of automatic data transfers from one machine to the other etc. It has *tons* of options. Even the free version is already pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [**SuperFlexible**](http://www.superflexible.com/), which supports FTP, FTPS, SFTP/SSH, WebDAV, SSL, HTTP, and Amazon S3 web storage.  There are Windows, Macintosh and Linux versions.

It's not free, but you may find it very useful.

[image: SuperFlexible]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check Cobian Backup (free);
http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm

You would be able to backup files on hdd, external disk and also some FTP. Powerfull and also simple to use.